# Angular efficiently using trackBy with ngFor

Tags: html, angular, performance, ngfor

In Angular, is the trackBy function necessary for *ngFor? I saw a few articles [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist), [here](https://medium.com/paramsingh-66174/catalysing-your-angular-4-app-performance-9211979075f6), [here](http://niisar.blogspot.com/2017/02/improving-angular-2-performance-in-ngfor.html), and [here](http://www.talkinghightech.com/en/angular-2-imporve-ngfor-preformance/) that say using trackBy will improve performance and has better memory management. But I was wondering if trackBy is such an improvement, then why isn't it default behavior? Is it default behavior and everything I am looking at is out of date?

If it isn't default behavior, my project has about 90 *ngFor in 90 components and I was wondering if there was a way to use the trackBy where I am not including the following function 90 times. I also want to avoid adding a service and importing that 90 times.

**HTML**

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let l of list; trackBy: trackByFn" [value]="l.id">
   {{l.name}}
</mat-option>
```

**TS**

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

notice that none of your examples use the index (besides one unreliable medium article), they all use a unique identifier of the object that angular can't possibly know unless you tell it.

Returning index alone has a use case but it's a fairly uncommon one. It's basically telling angular to never rerender the existing items in this list since the index of a given item will never change.  This usually is a very unexpected behavior for developers since the initialization lifecycle hooks of sub components won't reexecute. This is generally safe to do though in ngFor's that don't have sub components but these kinds of lists are generally more performant anyway and you won't see much benefit unless the lists are very long or change frequently.

The idea of trackBy is to allow you to reinitialize items in lists that need it and not reinitialize ones that don't.  It isn't a silver bullet for blindly increasing performance like some people treat it, it's purpose and functionality should be fully understood.  Keep in mind that just because an item has a unique ID doesn't mean it is appropriate to use in a trackBy function. trackBy is meant to tell angular when an item needs to be re-rendered, ie when I need those life cycle hooks to re run. If the ID stays the same but the contents can change, depending on how you've built a certain component, that component might need to be reinitialized anyway.

Comment: ok, so let's say I use `return item.id` instead. Since it is a unique identifier then I should see some memory/performance increase? and if it does, is there a cleaner way to use the trackBy without creating a function in every component?

Comment: item.id will definitely improve performance since angular will know when it does and does not need to re render items in your ngFor, but will obviously break if the items don't have an id property as many don't.  There is no global way to set trackBy as far as I know, nor would it make much sense since it would need to be overridden in some cases. The closest you could get is some kind of base "ListComponent" that implements a default trackByFn of your own design, but you would still need to explicitly declare its usage in your templates.

Comment: I edited my answer to be clearer / more detailed in the usage of trackBy

Comment: Thank you for the response, and lets assume all of my objects have id's because they all come from a db. We have a component where we add common functions, but we would need to add it to the import, providers, and constructor to be able to reference it in the html, which is the same number of lines as a `return item.id` function. I just wanted to see if there was an efficient way to add this without having to add so many lines of copied/pasted code

Comment: like I said, you can make a base list component class that implements the function and have any component with an ngFor inherit from it. This may be the same number of lines as importing and constructing, but it will be infinitely easier to change if it ever needs to be changed. If you get good enough with angular cli, you can actually set it up so that it can scaffold this component for you.

Comment: how does trackBy know that there is a change in a specific object if the object's reference is the same, even though the contents have changed?

Comment: it doesn't, so it won't rerender the component, remember rerendering is about running life cycle hooks, not about change detection of content on the screen. So anything bound to the screen will update properly even if trackBy is used so long as change detection runs and it isn't dependent on a life cycle hook running.

Comment: trackBy function is being recursively called on mouse move, is it valid?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Your trackBy shouldn’t be a complex function. It should return a simple value.

Answer (score 8):

Give it a class for test

```
export class Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

And add a directive to monitor its init and destory

```
@Directive({selector: '[appMonitor]'})
export class MonitorDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('init');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('destroy');
  }
}
```

Init an arrary

```
  itemArray: Item[] = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Tom'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Joe'},
    {id: 3, name: 'KK'}
  ];
```

Two functions to change the array content

```
  allFoo(): void {
    this.itemArray = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Tom_foo'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Joe_foo'},
      {id: 3, name: 'KK_foo'}
    ];
  }

  allBar(): void {
    this.itemArray = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Tom_bar'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Joe_bar'},
      {id: 3, name: 'KK_bar'}
    ];
  }
```

The preparation is done,so far so good.
First of all let's test without trackBy

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemArray " appMonitor>
    Id: {{item.id}} Name:{{item.name}}
  </div>
```

[image]

Clearlly every time you change the array angular has recreate component accordingly.Let's try trackBy this time:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemArray ;trackBy:identify" appMonitor>
  Id: {{item.id}} Name:{{item.name}}
</div>
```

Identity:

```
  identify(index: number, item: Item): number {
    return item.id;
  }
```

[image]

The component is being resued.So we can conclude that using trackBy can save the work from creating same component in hmtl.

Answer (score 6):

I have created an animation which shows how both `ngFor` and `ngFor` with `trackBy` manipulates `DOM` side by side.
[image]

read article here: https://link.medium.com/ckBRk9wrinb

Answer (score 2):

### An optimized solution:

Problem: Rendering views is an expensive task of O(n) list

---

Solution: we are typically rolling the viewport on scrolls which involves removing and adding with the same number of views. rather than deleting the views and creating them all again, we recycle them. So we detach the views, remove the context, and cache them so we can attach them and re-context them on the add cycle. Therefore saving a considerable number of script/render cycles. (In android it's called recycler view)

here is are few angular library that does that exactly as mentioned, better performance than trackBy function

1. https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview
2. https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller(this lib is no longer maintained and does not work with latest angular versions but if you still wanted to use copy-paste to your source and import in your module)
3. https://github.com/anagram4wander/ng-vfor-lib

Comment: going to the link gives a 404